# Why does which(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)) return the vector c(1, 3) in this R swirl tutorial?

Tags: r

In this link (http://www.simonqueenborough.info/R/basic/lessons/Logic.html), there is a point that says:"We can use the resulting logical vector to ask other questions about ints. The which() function takes a logical vector as an argument and returns the indices of the vector that are TRUE. For example which(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)) would return the vector c(1, 3)."

but I don't understand why which(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)) returns the vector c(1, 3)? Could someone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: `which` returns the indices of the elements of a vector that are `TRUE`. In this case, it is the first and third elements.

Comment: How is it the first and third elements? What do the first and third elements have anything to do with c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)?

Comment: `c(...)` puts its arguments into a vector. You have a TRUE, a FALSE and a TRUE (in that order), so c(T,F,T) is a logical vector with three elements.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.